# Show that if a and b are odd positive integers,and b does not divide a,then there are integers s and t such that $a=bs+t$ where t is odd and $|t| <b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $a$ and $b$ are odd positive integers, and $b$ does not divide $a$, then there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $ a = bs + t$ where $t$ is odd and $|t| <b$.

Let a = 2k +1 and b = 2j + 1 where k,j are positive integers.

since b does not divide a then there is a non-zero remainder on division by b.
we can write;

$a = bs + t$

now to show that $t$ is odd;

$(2k +1) = (2j + 1)s + t$

rearranging;

$2(k-2js) - ( s-1) = t$

$2(k-2js) + (1-s) = t$

$2[(k-2js) -s/2] + 1  = t$

Hence t is odd. but i have not shown that $|t| <b$.

In fact, i am questioning whether i have shown anything.

Comment: $|t|<b$ is asserted by the Euclidean division. (If you need to prove it, just look at any proof that Euclidean division exists in $\mathbf{Z}$.)

Comment: However, your proof is sketchy. For example, you write $s/2$, but do you know that $s$ is even?

Comment: ah i see. in that case it is very sketchy.

Comment: $5=3*1+2$ is a counterexample, right? Maybe I skimmed this too quickly?   **EDIT** - Oh, woops. This is not trying to prove this is true in every case. MAybe I can leave this so no other hasty readers make the same mistake.

Comment: could someone help me understand the answer below, i placed a comment below it. the even case is throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward method is by using the euclidian algorithm:

So by the euclidian algorithm, we find $q$ and $r$ such that
$$a = bq+r$$
and $0<|r|<|b| = b$. We consider two cases:

- $r$ is odd. We are done.
- $r$ is even, but in this case, $r-b$ is odd, so $$a = b(q+1)+(r-b)$$ and $-b < r-b < 0$ so $|r-b| < b$.

I think that almost every proof will require a (small) case-study.

Comment: this is great, but how can you justify replacing r with r-b?  i may be silly here. i have no idea why you have said, but in this case r - b is odd

Comment: I GOT IT, now worries all. thanks, many thanks!

Comment: looking back at this, whats the justification for r-b being odd if r is even, both r and b could very well be even.

Comment: Because b is odd.

Answer (score -1):

> **Note:** The following is more or less a rewrite of *JefLaga's* answer with a small additional hint in order to answer the detail which is asked by OP in the bounty text.
>
> It's a good idea to start as *JefLaga* did and use the *Euclidean algorithm*, because this way we can already assume the existence of *non-negative integers* $q$ and $r$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> a=bq+r\qquad\qquad 0\leq|r|<b
> \end{align*}
>   Since $b$ does *not* divide $a$ we observe
>   $$0<|r|<b$$
>
> So, the only thing we have to show is that $r$ is odd.

Let's recall the parity when adding/subtracting even and odd numbers:
\begin{array}{lcll}
\pm&|&even&odd\tag{1}\\
\hline&|\\
even&|&even&odd\\
odd&|&odd&even
\end{array}

> And as Jef did, we distinguish according to the parity of $r$
>
> - $r$ is odd: Nothing to show
> - $r$ is even: Now **since $b$ is odd**, we observe according to (1) that $r-b$ is odd *(even minus odd = odd)*
>
> and again we have a valid representation
>   $$a=b(q+1)+(r-b)$$
>   with an *odd* number $r-b$ as remainder and since $-b<r-b<0$ we observe: 
>   \begin{align*}
> |r-b|<b\qquad\qquad&\\
> &\Box
> \end{align*}

Comment: How do we know that b is odd?

Comment: I understand everything in that post, but what has been troubling me is that i cant see why b is odd? or is it the case that its odd when r is even? i'm clearly not seeing something.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: According to the problem we may *assume* that both, $a$ *and* $b$ are odd and we also may assume, that $b$ does not divide $a$. This is already stated in the problem. Regards,

Comment: Oh my days, I feel like such a tool. Thanks ever so much Markus

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: Don't worry. The main point is that everything's now clear to you! :-) Best regards,

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: Thanks for granting the bounty! :-)